# Difference on Applying Filter on Date Column With Data Type nvarchar and Date

Tags: sql-server, date, filter, format

I want to prepare an example on how filtering on date column with data type date `(yyyy-mm-dd)` and `nvarchar` would differ. So I have two columns in my table both containing date. Difference between 2 is that 1 is in date format and the other one is in `nvarchar` format.

```
+-------------+---------------------+
| Flight_Date | Flight_Date_Varchar |
+-------------+---------------------+
| 2021-01-07  | 2021-01-07          |
| 2021-01-07  | 2021-01-07          |
| 2021-01-07  | 2021-01-07          |
| 2021-01-07  | 2021-01-07          |
| 2021-01-07  | 2021-01-07          |
| 2021-01-07  | 2021-01-07          |
| 2021-01-07  | 2021-01-07          |
| 2021-02-07  | 2021-02-07          |
| 2021-02-08  | 2021-02-08          |
| 2021-02-09  | 2021-02-09          |
+-------------+---------------------+
```

I am finding it difficult to understand that why I am able to sort both the columns in ascending and descending order when 1 of the column is not in date format. Is there an example to show that how behavior would change when querying using `nvarchar` column instead of date column?

I've also tried applying date filter on both column still I am able to apply filter on column where date is stored in `nvarchar` format. I am looking for an example that demonstrates how filters would differ when applying filter on date column and date column where dates are stored in data type `nvarchar`

Comment: you are storing the date in `Flight_Date_Varchar` in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. So ORDER BY it ASC or DESC still works. Try storing date in `MM-DD-YYYY` or `DD-MM-YYYY` and repeat the same ordering test. Hopefully, at the end you will understand why it is important to use the correct `data type` to store your value

Comment: If you store a date as a string, then eventually two things will happen. A value will be stored that is not in your "expected" format (e.g., 1/7/21). And a value will be stored that is not a real date (0000-00-00). Problems like this are posted over and over and over. Choose the datatype that is appropriate for the domain of the attribute; let the database engine enforce the natural characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@squirrel is right, If you use `yyyy-mm-dd` format then the order by will work, instead if you change the format as `MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY` then you can see the difference.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Tempdate
CREATE TABLE #Tempdate (Id int, Flight_Date DATE, Flight_Date_Varchar NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #Tempdate
VALUES
(1,'10-12-2013','10-12-2013'),
(2,'01-11-2013','01-11-2013'),
(3,'01-01-2014','01-01-2014'),
(4,'01-03-2014','01-03-2014')

SELECT * FROM #Tempdate ORDER BY Flight_Date DESC

SELECT * FROM #Tempdate ORDER BY Flight_Date_Varchar DESC
```